# Как добавить frame?

Tags: javascript, css, site, frame

Как добавить фрейм на сайт, но то как именно я его вижу))) Вообщем добавить например фрейм сайта ВКонтакте но так чтобы пользователь моего сайта видел на сайте мою авторизированную страницу?

Comment: Вы про `iframe`?

Comment: да я про iframe

Comment: Но я буду рад услышать любой другой способ как это сделать

Comment: у iframe есть атрибут src. Вот в src и надо указать адрес страницы, которую надо отображать

Comment: Он отобразит человеку просто сайт ВК, а не мою страницу, перечитайте вопрос

Comment: Если ваша страница не закрыта от неавторизованных пользователей, то очевидно, что ссылка на нее как раз ее отобразит

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы человек увидел мою авторизированную страницу, то есть с моими переписками, с возможностью писать на стене и прочее

Comment: Сомневаюсь что такое вообще возможно.